# SKLearn 0.20.2 - Import error with RandomizedPCA?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, pip, installation, decomposition

I'm trying to do the Udacity mini project and I've got the latest version of the SKLearn library installed (20.2).

When I run:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import RandomizedPCA
```

I get the error:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'RandomizedPCA' from 'sklearn.decomposition' (/Users/kintesh/Documents/udacity_ml/python3/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/__init__.py)`

I actually even upgraded the version using:

`pip3 install -U scikit-learn`

Which upgraded from `0.20.0` to `0.20.2`, which also uninstalled and reinstalled... so I'm not sure why it can't initialise `sklearn.decomposition`.

Are there any solutions here that might not result in completely uninstalling python3 from my machine?! Would ideally like to avoid that.

Any help would be thoroughly appreciated!

Edit:

I'm doing some digging and trying to fix this, and it appears as though the `__init__.py` file in the `decomposition` library on the SKLearn GitHub doesn't reference `RandomizedPCA`... has it been removed or something?

[Link to the GitHub page](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/decomposition/__init__.py)

Answer (score 41):

As it turns out, `RandomizePCA()` was depreciated in an older version of SKLearn and is simply a parameter in `PCA()`.

You can fix this by changing the import statement to:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA as RandomizedPCA
```

... and then your classifier looks like this:

```
pca = RandomizedPCA(n_components=n_components, svd_solver='randomized', whiten=True).fit(X_train)
```

However, if you're here because you're doing the Udacity Machine Learning course on `Eigenfaces.py`, you'll notice that the `PIL` library is also deprecated.

Unfortunately I don't have a solution for that one, but [here's the GitHub issue page](https://github.com/udacity/ud120-projects/issues/154), and [here's](https://jefflirion.github.io/udacity/Intro_to_Machine_Learning/Lesson12.html) a kind hearted soul that used a Jupyter Notebook to solve their mini-project back when these repositories worked.

I hope this helps, and gives enough information for the next person to get into Machine Learning. If I get some time I might take a crack at recoding `eigenfaces.py` for `SKLearn 0.20.2`, but for now I'm just going to crack on with the rest of this course.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Aaraeus said, the `PIL library` has been forked to `Pillow`. 
You can fix the `PIL` import error using

```
pip3 install pillow
```